# Spam from Webupon

Tags: support, spam, blacklist

We seem to be getting an increasing amount of answers linking to the following page:

```
http://webupon.com/web-talk/yahoo-messenger-problem-solution-to-the-blank-im-screen/
```

The actual link appears to actually give instructions that muck up the registry more than anything..

Should we be blacklisting this site or something? It's just becoming a little too frequent, and all the answers look the same.

Comment: So far, [14 results](http://u.sbhat.me/rNQoNH) for posts which refer to webupon posts ( Mods only)

Comment: @Sathya Are most of them recent?

Comment: No, most are from September. 3-4 from this month and the past

Comment: If there's a recurring pattern of spam from them, we can ask a dev to blacklist it.

Comment: @nhinkle I've seen it at least 3 times this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered earlier, please email `team@stackexchange.com` if you have domain name blacklist requests.

Try to be *sure* the domain name is indeed a recurring problem before doing so, as many spam domains are quite ephemeral and last maybe one or two days before moving on...

Comment: Good to know. This one appears to have subsided.